# Set focus on input after page loading in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set focus on the first input of form after load page but it doesn't work!

```
$("#New").click(function() {
    var area = $(this).attr("name");      
    $("#txtHint").hide().load("add_data.php?area=" + area, function(){ 
        $(this).closest("form").find(':input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
    }).fadeIn('slow');
    //$(this).closest("form").find(':input:enabled:visible:first').focus();  
});
```

Can I have some help?

Comment: With the syntax highlighting above, you can see that you have not closed the double quotes correctly.

Comment: fix syntax error and try again: `$("#txtHint").hide().load("add_data.php?area=" + area, function(){...}); `

Comment: @scrowler Also [a selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: I would just add the autofocus attribute to the markup in PHP

Comment: the code has many parameters so I let only one "area" so I made mistake when I delete the rest params, however the focus still doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have this code:

```
<form id="formId">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

write this JQuery code:

```
$("#formId input:text").first().focus();
```

wrapped with the

```
$(document).ready();
```

Comment: I want the focus to be when the button clicked

Comment: simply $("#button").click(function(){ $("#formId input:text").first().focus(); });

Comment: if you read the question: I am trying to make focus after load page

Comment: exactly buddy you just add this to your jquery $(document).ready( $("#formId input:text").first().focus(); )  that code will automatically focus on the first value as soon as the page is loaded completely

Comment: If you have any other question don't hesitate to ask me if not I will be thankful to be chosen as the right answer of that post

Answer (score 0):

Your code rewrite as

```
$("#txtHint").hide().load("add_data.php?area=" + area, function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#inputId").focus();
});
```